# How to deal with coordinates in multiple regression

Tags: r

I have a question that wants me to estimate the effect of Nitrogen fertilizer, Phosphorus fertilizer, Rainfall, sowing date and location on the yield of some crop. However, the location is given in coordinates (I.e. longitude and latitude data sets). 
How do I factor in the coordinates? Should they be treated as dummy variables or factors?
PS: the dataset has 100 observations

Comment: Not a good question for stackoverflow. You need to have a strategy in mind and show some data and coding efforts.

Comment: Unless you want to explicitly use spatial statistics, you would have to use dummy variables either in terms of zip codes or states or some administrative level that makes sense for you data. A good starting point for you may be this: https://blog.exploratory.io/geocoding-us-zip-code-data-with-dplyr-and-zipcode-package-7f539c3702b0

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of problem solving and not code, the way to make your latitudes and longitudes useful is to find the growing zones for USDA

If you are interested in the best possible outcomes,
 look up the weather at those areas based on the lat, lon. With sufficient years of data you should be able to build a more predictive model than just the base model with just nutrients.